# How to set options of Beautify extension in the Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, js-beautify

I installed Beautify extension to VSC, however, I could not find *.jsbeautifyrc* file to set some options. For example, I want to set "brace_style" to ""collapse,preserve-inline". How can I change extension's parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create your own `.jsbeautify` file in your project directory or any containing folder. Please refer to this link for an example file: https://gist.github.com/wzup/fc3254562236c1ec3f69

Here you can also see some of the parameters which you can change. In your case:

```
{
 "html": {
          "brace_style": "collapse"
         }
}
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.